# Is there a way to have a column reference one of two columns on seperate tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating a system that has `Posts` and `Comments`. The `Posts` reference to a `Location` as seen below.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS reference_id;
   ...

CREATE TABLE Posts 
(
    id BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('reference_id') PRIMARY KEY,
    username INTEGER
        REFERENCES Users,
    location_id INTEGER
        REFERENCES Locations,
    created_at timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    subject TEXT,
    body text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Comments 
(
    id BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('reference_id') PRIMARY KEY,
    username INTEGER
        REFERENCES Users,
    reference_id INTEGER
        REFERENCES Posts,
    created_at timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    body text NOT NULL
);
```

I have created a sequence so that both `Posts` and `Comments` can share a set of ids, so they are all unique. But now, I need the `Comments` to reference either a `Post` ***OR*** another `Comment`. Like

```
reference_id INTEGER
        REFERENCES Posts OR Comments,
```

I'm thinking I might have to create a third table, but even that seems... obscure to me. Every time I think about it, it seems I'm stuck in some sort of recursive loop of "well, this comment is a child level which will link to posts, and then I need a grandchild level comment that references just child level comments, and then I need a great-grandchild level comment..."

Is there a way to do this? Preferably without a third table, but whatever works, I'll take.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for an `OR` reference.

Have two nullable columns, one for each FK:

```
CREATE TABLE Comments (
  ...
  posts_reference_id INTEGER REFERENCES Posts,
  comments_reference_id INTEGER REFERENCES Comments,
  ...
)
```

Or since you seem to want comments and posts to be an interchangeable FK, delete the `comments` table and introduce a `post_type` column that can be either `'post'` or `'comment'`

Comment: If I delete the comments table (as in your secondary suggestion), I still wind up with two `reference_id` columns, as main posts will be referencing `Locations` and comments will be referencing `Posts`.

Comment: I'm going to attempt to use the separated, nullable columns. If that winds up working out, I'll accept the answer. Thanks for the help.